# Manipulating Cookies before serving

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

#### Scenario

I have a simple NodeJS server using the Express framework. I have some ReactJS pages that I need to serve. No Isomorphic for now.

Before serving, I want to check if the user has a particular cookie and then based on that I want to create a new cookie.

#### What I tried

Here is the code for my `server.js` file.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var Cookies = require("cookies");

app.use(function(req, res){
  var cookies = new Cookies( req, res);
  var userCookie = cookies.get("sso");
  var isLoggedIn = cookies.get("isLoggedIn");

  if(userCookie !== undefined && isLoggedIn === false){
    cookies.set("isLoggedIn", true);
  }
});


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

So I am using `express.static` for serving static files from my `build` folder.

I tried moving the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));` line above the previous `app.use`, but then the code never enters the cookies section.

I tried this simple thing. Even this didn't worked. I can see log `hello`, but the website isn't working.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res){
  console.log("hello");
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jeremy's answer pointed out, I was using the cookies the wrong way. But that wasn't the core problem. If code would have run, express server would have thrown error. The real problem was that i wasn't calling the next middleware in the application’s request-response cycle. According to the [docs](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html)

> Middleware is a function with access to the request object (req), the
>   response object (res), and the next middleware in the application’s
>   request-response cycle, commonly denoted by a variable named next.

I wasn't calling the `next`.

So the updated running code is:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var Cookies = require("cookies");

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var cookies = new Cookies( req, res);
  var userCookie = cookies.get("sso");
  var isLoggedIn = cookies.get("isLoggedIn");

  if(userCookie !== undefined && isLoggedIn !== "true"){
    cookies.set("isLoggedIn", "true",{ httpOnly: false } );
  }
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8142;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with your use of cookies. You're checking if `isLoggedIn`, the cookie value, `=== false`, a boolean value. But cookies are always strings, so the comparison will always be `false` and you'll never set `isLoggedIn` to `"true"`.

If your update your code to treat the values as strings it might work. Try something like this:

```
if(userCookie !== undefined && isLoggedIn !== "true"){
  cookies.set("isLoggedIn", "true");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But that also didn't worked. Updated my 2nd attempt.